# How to get the PID of a process called by a script from the script parent script

Tags: bash, pid

I have the following problem: I have a script that execute an internal background process by:

```
====myinternalscript====
...
myinternalscript-program &
...
```

Which is called from a scripts that waits for the **myinternalscript-program** termination by:

```
====mainscript====
...
myinternalscript
while [ "$(ps -u ${CURRENT_USER} | grep myinternalscript-program)" ];
...
```

The problem comes when I want to call **mainscript** again before the first call ends. This makes that if **myinternalscript-program** related to the first call ends before the second **myinternalscript-program** finishes, the pause condition on the first call to **mainscript** is still true (because the **myinternalscript-program** called by the second **mainscript** call) and the first **mainscript** call doesn't advance until the **myinternalscript-program** called by the second **mainscript** also finishes.

My solution would be:

```
====mainscript====
...
myinternalscript
internalpid = #some way to get the myinternalscript-program PID
while [ "$(ps -u ${CURRENT_USER} | grep myinternalscript-program| grep $internalpid)" ];
...
```

Where "internalpid" has the PID of the **myinternalscript-program** called during the execution of **myinternalscript**.

As suggested by one of the answers, $! after the **myinternalscript-program** could give me the PID information I require on **myinternalscript** and then I could imagine some way to get that information to **mainscript**, but I have no permissions to edit **myinternalscript**. In this context the challenge is:

> How to get the **myinternalscript-program** PID at **mainscript**
>   without editing **myinternalscript**?

Obviously I could also use some other way to pause the **mainscript** execution to solve the issue, but it puzzles me if what I wanted to do originally can be achieved.

Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

The PID of the current script is in the $$ bash variable.  No need to parse ps output.

Answer (score 0):

You may create PID file from your scripts in other terminal.

```
echo $$ > /tmp/script1.pid
```

and then you have to check it in your script

```
checkpid=$(cat /tmp/script1.pid)
while [ "x$(ps $checkpid | grep -v PID)" != "x" ];do echo still running;sleep 1;done
```

or if you can run scripts in same terminal (how many I realize you need run it parallel) you may run it in background and use "wait" keyword to wait for background jobs:

```
script1.sh &
script2.sh &
wait
echo "scripts finished"
```